# Multi-dimensional array to HTTP-like array

Tags: php, arrays, json, encoding

To fill a form on the client I need to pack the form data into a flat json.

I need to encode `['foo'=>['x'=>'a','y'=>'b']]` to `{"foo[x]":"a","foo[y]":"b"}` and

```
['foo'=>['x'=>['z'=>'a','y'=>['b','d']]]]` → 

{"foo[x][z]":"a","foo[x][y][]":"b","foo[x][y][]":"d"]}
```

and so on.

How should I do that in PHP? Is there any function out of the box?

json_encode results `{"foo":{"x":"a","y":"b"}}` which is not in the desired format.

Comment: `json_encode()` maybe?

Comment: {"foo[x]":"a","foo[y]":"b"}  that is not valid json by the way

Comment: `{"foo[x]":"a","foo[y]":"b"}` is not valid json by the way

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420: Why not?

Comment: @RaggaMuffin-420 It is, as long as the field names are correctly quoted it's perfectly valid, regardless of what's in it.

Comment: Why does it need to be in that format?  Are you using this to create `<input>` elements?

Comment: @scragar Ok actually what i meant was, that json doesnt map to the array quoted!

Comment: So you don't want JSON?

Comment: @AbraCadaver: `{"foo[x]":"a","foo[y]":"b"}` is JSON.

Comment: @RocketHazmat: Yes, but is not the same data as the PHP array, so the desired result is a totally different array encoded in JSON.

Comment: What happens if you have a numerical array containing elements itself, sort of like `$array = [ "a1" => [ "b1" ,[ "c1" => "abc", "c2" => "def" ], "b3" ], "a2"=>"ghi" ]` ?

Comment: `{"a1[b1][c1]":"abc","a1[b1][c2]":"def","a1[]":"b3","a2":"ghi"}`

Comment: @PHPst: Try using `http_build_query()` to turn your array into a query string, then parse it back into a single-level array.